SuiteScript server side script set shipaddresslist on Item Fulfillment
I am trying to find out if it's possible to set shipaddresslist on the Item Fulfillment record through a server side script and have it update the shipping address. I am able to do this on the Purchase Order via a user event script in the after submit event. I have tried to do this on the Item Fulfillment record through a user event script in after submit and before submit and it is not updating the shipping address. I have also tried to set the shipaddresslist on the Item Fulfillment record through a scheduled script that creates an Item Fulfillment record through a transform on the sales order. I had the same results.
If I log the Item Fulfillment record before saving it I see that the shipaddresslist has been updated but the address lines are not updated. I have tried saving the Item Fulfillment with sourcing enabled and without and it doesn't matter.
Has anyone been able to set the shipping address list by setting the shipaddresslist to a specific address id via a server script on the Item Fulfillment record? A NetSuite support contact told me it was possible but I have not seen it work yet.

I found the solution from the answer to this post How to set the "Ship To Select" shipping address dropdown field for a Sales Order? I had to set the shipaddress to null and then setting shipaddresslist worked.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
